# Identify DIP8 IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Can anyone identify this DIP8 IC from a 1980s circuit board? A Google search of the markings doesn't turn up anything, at least not for me. Could be an inverter, buffer or timer based on the board, but I am not sure.

- Pin 1 is 5V to 12V+
- Pin 3 is the input
- Pin 4 is not connected
- Pin 5 is GND
- Pin 6 is the output

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: "8535" is most probably the date code, since you say it's from the 80s. Could you [edit] your question to show more of the surrounding, please, optimally as schematic?

Comment: @the-busybee Schematic added

Comment: Is it from something like an old BMW instrument cluster?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, old instrument cluster

Comment: I kind of suspect it's a custom part made for VDO (something like a tachometer chip), but maybe you'll get a better answer.